# React Native create a complete hybrid app on Windows with react-native cli

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

Is it possible to create a React Native app with react-native cli on a Windows PC and configure it for both Android and iOS on the Windows PC and then just build it on a macOS device for iOS? Do I need XCode for any of the iOS configuration or is it possible to do everything on a windows PC? I don't want to create any custom native libraries, only download some react-native ones.

I do not want to use expo because the apps built with expo are too big. But I don't have access to a mac device so I would like to be able to do everything on windows beside compilation and then just rent a cloud mac to compile for iOS.

Comment: Without a max you won't be able to upload to the App Store.  All the App Store tools are built into XCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to distribute your application to the AppStore and/or test your app on an iPhone and/or iOS Emulator, you **must** use Xcode, which means you **must** have a Mac or a virtual machine that runs MAC OS.

Most of the configuration is pretty much done on your windows machine except some settings and app icon, splash screen, all these things require you to set it up via XCode. Hopefully it suffices as an answer.